# Определение загрузочного раздела

Tags: linux, fdisk

Как определить загрузочный раздел?

Нашёл, что в утилите *parted* можно посмотреть таблицу раздела и по флагу *boot* определить, является ли он загрузочным.

```
Number  Start   End     Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000MB  999MB  fat32              boot, esp
 2      1000MB  240GB   239GB  ext4
```

Проблема в том, что не на всех системах этот флаг вносится в раздел (возможно, что только на старых не вносится).

```
Minor  Start   End      Filesystem  Flags
1      0,000   101,944  ext3
```

Ещё, старые версии *fdisk* выводили столбец *boot*, помечая загрузочный раздел звёздочкой:

```
Device     Boot  Start   End  Block    Id   System
/dev/hda1  *     1       13   104391   83   Linux
/dev/hda2        14      267  2040255  82   Swap Linux
```

Однако в современных версиях этого столбца нет.

```
Device     Start   End      Sectors  Size   Type
/dev/sda1  2048    1953791  1951744  953M   EFI System
```

Есть ли какой-нибудь универсальный и не очень громоздкий способ?

Comment: в случае использования efi-загрузчика и efi-раздела, этот флаг вообще не имеет смысла: загружаться-то будет не код из первого сектора, а один из файлов, записанных внутри efi-раздела.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin как же быть?

Comment: зависит от того, **для чего** вам нужна эта информация.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin мне нужно определить установленный загрузчик